# Interface inheritance in non-Struct types

Tags: inheritance, go, interface

I'm currently learning interfaces in Go, but I've gotten stuck with this piece of code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

// CommonMath is a common interface for math types
type CommonMath interface {
    Abs() float64
}

// Float64 is a custom float64 type
type Float64 float64

// Abs returns the modulus of objects implementing CommonMath
func (f Float64) Abs() float64 {
    if f < 0 {
        return -float64(f)
    }
    return float64(f)
}

// AbsSquared returns the square of objects implementing CommonMath
func AbsSquared(num CommonMath) float64 {
    return num.Abs() * num.Abs()
}

func main() {
    var f Float64
    f = -5

    type newF Float64
    var newFloat newF
    newFloat = 10.5

    fmt.Println(f)
    fmt.Println(f.Abs())
    fmt.Println(AbsSquared(newFloat))
}
```

As it turns out, it doesn't compile because `newFloat` does not implement the interface `CommonMath`. Being of type `newF`, which is a custom Float64 type that implements the interface, I don't know what's going on. To make things weirder, I substituted the declaration of newF and newFloat for the following, which implements the same but as a struct:

```
type newF struct {
    Float64
}
newFloat := newF{10.5}
```

Suddenly, the code builds perfectly fine. Does this mean that only structs can implement parent types' interfaces, and therefore declaring the type `newF` directly as `Float64` is not allowed?

Comment: First, there is no inheritance in Go, which probably is part of the confusion. The only reason to declare `newF` is to remove the methods. If you don't want to create a new method set for `newF`, don't use a new type.

Comment: Maybe inheritance is not the word, but derived structs do implement the interfaces their parent's implement. Why doesn't that happen with other types?

Comment: Nothing ever "inherits" methods. Your struct has an embedded `Float64` field, and the methods are automatically delegated to the `Float64` implementation. See [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) in Effective Go and in the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is no inheritance in the Go , at all. There are several article across the web to discussing the design decision of Go discarding many feature of `oop` but that is really beyond this answer.

Into your case. It is very clear that `Float64` implements `CommonMath`. It has the method sets that `CommonMath` requires so it fits into the interface.

However, when you declare another type, `type newF Float64`, the new type does not copy the method sets, only the data structure. This is specified in the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions):

> A type definition creates a new, distinct type with the same underlying type and operations as the given type, and binds an identifier to it.
>
> The new type is called a defined type. It is different from any other type, including the type it is created from.
>
> A defined type may have methods associated with it. It does not inherit any methods bound to the given type, but the method set of an interface type or of elements of a composite type remains unchanged:

```
// A Mutex is a data type with two methods, Lock and Unlock.
type Mutex struct         { /* Mutex fields */ }
func (m *Mutex) Lock()    { /* Lock implementation */ }
func (m *Mutex) Unlock()  { /* Unlock implementation */ }

// NewMutex has the same composition as Mutex but its method set is empty.
type NewMutex Mutex
// The method set of the base type of PtrMutex remains unchanged,
// but the method set of PtrMutex is empty.
type PtrMutex *Mutex

// The method set of *PrintableMutex contains the methods
// Lock and Unlock bound to its embedded field Mutex.
type PrintableMutex struct {
    Mutex
}

// MyBlock is an interface type that has the same method set as Block.
type MyBlock Block
```

And next come to `type NewF struct { Float64 }`. On a first look, this looks very much to inheritance but once again there is no such thing in Go. It is called **embedding** or **composition**. Again, the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an embedded field. An embedded field must be specified as a type name T or as a pointer to a non-interface type name *T, and T itself may not be a pointer type. The unqualified type name acts as the field name.
>
> A field or method f of an embedded field in a struct x is called promoted if x.f is a legal selector that denotes that field or method f.
>
> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they cannot be used as field names in composite literals of the struct.
>
> Given a struct type S and a type named T, promoted methods are included in the method set of the struct as follows:
>
> - If S contains an embedded field T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S also includes promoted methods with receiver *T.
> - If S contains an embedded field *T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T or *T.

So, the trick here is **promotion**. The method of `Float64` gets promoted to `NewF`. Again it may looks like inheritance in some way, but it is distinct. Please note that the promoted method still belongs to the embedded type, and the receiver will always be the orignal one. The following code print 4.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {}

type B struct {A}

func (A) P() int {
    return 4
}

func (B) P() int {
    return 5
}

func (a A) S() {
    fmt.Println(a.P())
}

func main() {
    B{}.S()
}
```

playground: https://play.golang.org/p/BuBL69LqeY6

Comment: Thanks! That explains a lot. Wish there was a way to use embeddings in non-Struct types.